# Chopping excess bits off an imported stl :)

Tags: 3d-printing

quite a beginner to blender, have rendered a rough 3d model of a battery compartment for a '78 Triumph Bonneville and imported it, but it's got lots of bits I need to slice off and delete. Then I'll need to quarter it for printing. Dont understand how to chop stuff with Blender, please help guys! :)[image: image not shown in blender, but in the app where it was constructed][image]
The images shown are from the app where the stl was constructed

Comment: Please clarify your subject line and description, including adding screenshot of what you're referring to. That will greatly help your chance of getting help!

Comment: Thanks, will do :)

Answer (score 0):

To chop off stuff, there is an option in Blender, I believe, to delete disconnected parts of a mesh. You can also use the removed doubles option to remove overlapping vertices. If you want to remove triangles as well, you can press Alt+J to remove them as well.

Comment: Thanks I'll look up those options :) I wonder how I can select and disconnect those parts first though?

Comment: I think there may be a select option in Blender to select disconnected parts. Actually, nevermind on that part. If you press A to select everything, you can press Alt+J and remove doubles and it will be able to determine what is disconnected and what is not. Those are options that would probably be better to have as the last step. First, you need to deselect everything (Alt+A)  and then click on the option that says to select disconnected edges. After that is done, the disconnected parts should be gone and using the two methods I mentioned earlier, it will help to clean up the model.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful :) however I still don't know how to actually disconnect the parts I don't want, does anybody know how to do this?